# Bar.class reference in JavaPoet

Tags: java, javapoet

I have a method that takes a class, e.g. `public foo(Class<?> barClass)`. Using [JavaPoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) I want to pass construct an invocation of this method. Currently I'm using this form:

```java
ClassName barClassName = ClassName.get("com.example", "Bar");

…
  .addStatement("foo($T.class)", barClassName)
…
```

That works well enough, but I'm wondering if JavaPoet has some facility to construct the `Bar.class` form, such as `barClassName.literalReference()` or some such.

Comment: As far as I know, JavaPoet doesn't have API to create any kind of specific expressions (e.g. if you want to generate "a + b" you have to use a string literal *somewhere*). Why would you expect there be anything to generate a class literal?

Comment: I had no expectations one way or the other. I was just inquiring. I didn't want to do something manually if there existed a facility for this.

Comment: Can you reword your question without foo and bar? I can't understand a thing you're trying to do. Could you use actual words in place of foo and bar?